# Why should we not get haircut and shave (trimming nails) when wife is pregnant

Tags: scripture, smriti

Can someone tell me what are the rituals to be followed by a brahmin when the wife is pregnant?

I've heard that we should not cut hair and shave?

Is it only shave or haircut also? Should both be abstained? But why it should be abstained when wife is pregnant? Are trimming nails also forbidden?

(I also understand that, when a relation passes away, the person performing the last rites of the departed soul also do not shave the beard? Why is that and what is the reason for this mentioned in our shastra and scriptures)

Also, if anyone can thrown in other points that the husband must not do while wife is pregnant?

Comment: Anyone can provide an answer?

Comment: See the answer to this question which incidentally touches upon this topic. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/shaving-haircut-nailcut-what-days-are-allowed-prohibited Also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/guidance-about-visiting-temples-after-a-13th-day-of-death-of-any-family-member/44349#44349

Comment: generally shaving and haircut are done together. the modern western practice of only shaving not haircut is not accepted by shastras.

Comment: For the husband of a pregnant wife during the pregnancy period (Apastamba Grihya Sutra). This from the answers linked in comments. Search there

Comment: https://www.tamilbrahmins.com/threads/shaving-and-hair-cutting-during-wife-pregnancy.29409/

Comment: Anyone can provide an answeR?

Comment: How did you get to know this @mar can you provide me a source for this statement

Comment: @LSSJBroly - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/shaving-haircut-nailcut-what-days-are-allowed-prohibited

Answer (score 1):

> **Garbhini Pati Dharmas**: During the period of pregnancy, the husband of the Garbhini too has certain duties. His major responsibility of course to to please her by fulfilling her small and big desires  that would indeed result in the birth of a healthy child with long and happy life. Besides he has to observe a few but significant tasks: he should not have Samudra Snaana, not resort to cut trees, to shave his head or face, not to travel by Seas or other wise, not even undertake Tirtha Yatras, not to carry dead bodies , not to take up new activities of house construction, not to cut nails; not to take up weddings, Upanayanas and such other Karyas, and not to offer Pinda Daanaas, attend Preta Karmas and so on if possible.However, some opine that performing the Pratyabdika Ceremonies of one’s own parents need not be disturbed although Dasrsha-Mahalaya Karmas may not be performed.
>       [Essence of DharmaSindu (Tritiya Paricheeda PurvaBhaga)](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=15) condensed by Sri VDN Rao (devotee of Kanchi Kamakoti Peetam)

PS - *If you are a follower of Vaidhyanatha Dikshitiyam ,Apastamba Grihya Sutra  you may procure the same for any reference .  /consult an eminent upadhyay/shastri of your sect, to know your sectarian variation.*